# Customize Laravel Jetstream Error Page with inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I have a Project **Laravel Jetstream with inertia** i need change the error page Like This to **Vue page**
[image]

I use https://inertiajs.com/error-handling but not work
[image]

```
public function render($request, Throwable $e)
{
    $response = parent::render($request, $e);

    if (/*!app()->environment(['local', 'testing']) &&*/in_array($response->status(), [500, 503, 404, 403])) {
        return Inertia::render('Error', ['status' => $response->status()])
            ->toResponse($request)
            ->setStatusCode($response->status());
    } else if ($response->status() === 419) {
        return back()->with([
            'message' => 'The page expired, please try again.',
        ]);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Hi, please do not post code images but rather actual text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work only in production
to work in local

remove `!app()->environment(['local', 'testing'])` from the code